# 7# Emertxe Gnidocne

Tags: cipher

I think the time has came.

[ ...em pleh ot uoy deen I ]

This is going to be the last puzzle.

[ qǝɔɐnsǝ ı,ɯ ƃoıuƃ ʇo 646965˙˙˙]

Where am I... That's my question... I can't say any more...

Help me,
 and... **Do not give up.**

Hint?:

[image: ...]

¿st_

*[Recall what you've done.]*

Comment: "Gnidocnee"  Dammit, now I'm hungry

Comment: I know what it actually *is*, but every time I see "Emertxe" I think it's something in Basque or Albanian

Comment: Your clue is a broken link?

Comment: It was once a working link. You could have checked the link before.

Comment: @Kevin When I saw `Gnidocne` I thought of `genocide` so your comment about hunger *really* startled me.

Answer (score 27):

I'm stuck at the moment but this is what I got so far:

Rotating and flipping all texts correctly should give:

```
Encoding Extreme #7

I think the time has came.  
I need you to help me  
This is going to be the last puzzle.  
because I'm going to die. (646965 is hex for "die")  
Where am I.. That's my question... I can't say any more...  
Help me, and... Do not give up
```

Then I noticed the question was edited and checked the history. What appeared were 2 things:

- Two lines were deleted:

> 546865206b69646e6170706572732073617920492063616e20646f2061206c617374207468696e6720492077616e742e2e2e
>
> 49206465636964656420746f206d616b652061206c6173742070757a7a6c652e2e2e20553238676557393149474e686269426f5a5778774947316c4c693475

- There is Brainfuck code hidden:

> +[----->+++<]>+.++++++++++++..----.[-->+<]>++.-----------..+[->++<]>+.+++++++++++.-------.[--->+<]>+.[->+++<]>+.+++++.--------.-[->+++<]>-.--[--->+<]>-.+++.

The two lines that were deleted are hex encoded for:

> The kidnappers say I can do a last thing I want...
>
> I decided to make a last puzzle... U28geW91IGNhbiBoZWxwIG1lLi4u

U28geW91IGNhbiBoZWxwIG1lLi4u is Base64 for

> So you can help me...

The Brainfuck code translates to

> http://alexinf.cf

On the bottom left of that website is fine printed:

> -[----->+<]>...+.-...+.-...+++.---...++++++.------...+++.---...+.-...-.+...---.+++...++++.----...++++++.------...+++.---.+++.---.+++.---...++++.----...++.--...-.+...---.+++...+++.---.+++.---.-.+...+++.---.+++.---.++.--...+++.---.+++.---.+++.---...++++.----...++++.----.....+++.---.+++.---.-.+.---.+++.+.-.++++++.------.++.+.---..-.+.++++.----.+++..--.--.--.++++++.----[->++<]>-.+[-->+<]>++++.---[->++<]>.[-->+<]>+++.---.+++.-----[->++<]>.[-->+<]>+++++.-.+.--.--.[->++<]>+.-[-->+<]>.[->++<]>+.-[-->+<]>.[->++<]>+.

and

> 546865206b69646e6170706572732073617920492063616e20646f2061206c617374207468696e6720492077616e742e2e2e

and

> 49206465636964656420746f206d616b652061206c6173742070757a7a6c652e2e2e20553238676557393149474e686269426f5a5778774947316c4c693475

The brainfuck code is

> 3334333433363339333633343332333033373339333636363337333533323330333636323336363533363636333733373333363632303439356332373664206c6f636b65642e2e2e

That last part is hex coding again, which partially leads to new hex code twice which leads to

> Did you know? I'm locked...

The other two things are the exact same hex codes that were deleted from this puzzle earlier on.

And now I'm stuck...

Comment: Eencoding Extreme #7 - there's an extra e. No idea if it's relevant to anything, though.

Comment: I think the hint image is encoded as a series of greyish pixels down the lefthand column of pixels. 52 colors in the image, no metadata I can find. But got no good graphics program on this machine. If I had to guess, I'd say low byte of R, G and B will be hex values.

Comment: If you mess with the levels or exposure, they're really quite colorful. I haven't found a tweak that reveals any meaningful information yet, though.

Comment: Dew Morgan: Think: It's not "Eencoding"...

Comment: It actually says Did you know? I'm locked...  3x. Edited. Eencoding  could also be interpreted as gennocide. Also misspelled.

Comment: ok, but it looks like the image contains 153 encoded pixels, anyone got any bright ideas on how to manipulate them? I also don't have excellent graphics programs avail right now...

Comment: Yah, its the last bits, but I don't have something to scrape the data efficiently...

Comment: or maybe it's not, the first chars would be T&¡, maybe it's the 7th bit because its the 7th puzzle?

Comment: @Z.Dailey I managed to parse the image in Java but I absolutely am not knowledgable in these kind of codes so I don't know what to do with it. What I did notice is that the R G and B value is never more than 3 values away from white. Check my code here: http://pastebin.com/0KuUnSwK

Comment: @IvoBeckers having the full RGB values may be of more use, I dont think it is solely the low bit of the values, but I can fix those and get the full values... I'll start digging.

Comment: tried 7th and 8th bits as well as 7and8 in RGB order and following down the R,G, and B columns to no avail.  This is a tough one, but it does say *Do not give up...*

Comment: Got another idea. Let's see what happens.

Comment: @Z.Dailey Can you get the palette indexes for the colours in the left column?  There's 52 of them, that could correspond to upper and lower case letters?

Answer (score 6):

An attempt to deobfuscate the data in the image:

```
FromCharacterCode[
 FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ 
  Partition[
   Flatten[IntegerDigits[
     BitAnd[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/dN9p4.png", 
        "Data"][[;; 153, 1]], 3], 2, 2]], 8]]
```

yeilds:

```
98&4f#ti%dc83.61.210.48-2016-03-18T12:04:01+01:0098&4f#ti%dcxÚ3UÈ,V(ÉHUHÌ+.O-âåâåÉH,Q/V(ÏH-JUðTHÌ\.05\.00Í6\.0b.98&4f#ti%d
```

Of note is:

- The ISO 8601 timestamp `2016-03-18T12:04:01+01:00` (about seven hours before this puzzle was first posted)
- The repeating sequence `98&4f#ti%dc`.  It occurs at the beginning, middle, and end (but missing the `c` in the last occurrence).
- The characters `83.61.210.48` could be an IP address.  It belongs to a [telecom company in Spain](http://whois.domaintools.com/83.61.210.48) (which matches the `+01:00` time zone).
- Analysis of the remaining piece of the string suggests some kind of Base85 encoding.

Answer (score 3):

Deep lore from the DECIPHER discord showed me that the string `98&4f#ti%dc` (as shown in @2012rcampion's answer) is characteristic of this online stego tool:

https://manytools.org/hacker-tools/steganography-encode-text-into-image/go/

After uploading the attached image to this site and clicking "decode", I find... the answer?

```
5 is the answer

That's where I am
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer:
For the image, here are the RGB values of the left column.

```
Blue Red Green
254 252 255
255 253 252
252 254 252
254 254 253
253 252 255
254 252 253
252 253 254
255 254 252
253 253 255
254 252 253
252 254 253
253 254 253
253 253 254
254 252 253
252 252 255
252 255 254
252 252 255
254 255 252
252 255 254
254 255 253
252 252 255
254 253 252
252 255 254
254 255 252
252 252 255
255 253 252
252 252 252
254 254 255
253 252 255
255 252 252
252 254 252
253 254 255
252 252 255
255 254 252
252 252 252
253 255 252
253 252 255
254 254 252
252 255 253
252 255 252
252 252 255
254 255 252
252 255 253
253 255 252
254 252 255
253 252 253
252 253 252
253 255 252
252 252 255
255 254 252
252 254 254
252 255 252
253 252 255
255 252 252
252 254 254
252 255 252
252 252 255
254 253 252
252 254 255
252 255 252
252 252 255
255 253 252
252 254 254
252 255 252
252 252 255
255 252 252
252 254 253
252 255 254
253 252 254
255 254 252
253 253 252
254 254 253
252 252 254
255 255 253
253 253 252
253 254 254
253 252 254
254 253 253
253 253 252
255 254 252
254 253 255
253 252 255
252 254 254
255 255 252
253 253 253
252 253 255
252 254 252
252 254 255
253 253 253
254 254 252
255 254 252
253 252 254
254 253 252
253 252 253
253 253 253
252 252 254
255 255 252
254 252 252
252 254 255
254 254 255
255 253 252
254 255 252
255 255 253
254 254 252
253 255 254
254 253 255
255 252 254
253 254 253
254 252 252
252 254 255
253 254 253
252 252 254
255 252 254
253 252 253
252 252 253
255 254 255
253 253 253
254 254 252
255 254 252
255 252 255
254 253 252
254 252 252
253 255 253
254 252 254
253 253 253
255 253 255
253 252 252
252 253 253
254 253 252
252 252 255
252 255 252
253 252 253
252 252 252
252 252 255
252 255 253
254 255 253
254 252 252
254 255 252
252 255 254
253 255 254
254 252 255
254 252 252
252 253 254
252 255 253
253 253 254
254 254 252
253 252 255
252 255 253
254 253 254
254 253 252
253 253 253
252 254 253
252 253 254
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255
```